# django query datetime filed issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

i have tried to apply filter datetime filed in django query,but i got  result zero

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    customer_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    phone_office = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    phone_residential = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    contact_person_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    cr_limit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    gstin = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    opening_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    opening_balance_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    payments_terms = models.ForeignKey(PaymentTerms, related_name='customer_terms', null=True, blank=True)
    address_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(SAUser, related_name='+')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the below code i have tried:

```
Customers.objects.filter(created_at__month=1).count()
```

but i have look at the query also

```
Customers.objects.filter(created_at__month=1).query
```

it seems like that

```
SELECT `customer_customers`.`id`, `customer_customers`.`first_name`, `customer_customers`.`last_name`, `customer_customers`.`customer_code`, `customer_customers`.`reference`, `customer_customers`.`phone_office`, `customer_customers`.`phone_residential`, `customer_customers`.`contact_person_first_name`, `customer_customers`.`mobile`, `customer_customers`.`email`, `customer_customers`.`fax`, `customer_customers`.`cr_limit`, `customer_customers`.`gstin`, `customer_customers`.`state_code`, `customer_customers`.`country`, `customer_customers`.`opening_balance`, `customer_customers`.`opening_balance_date`, `customer_customers`.`payments_terms_id`, `customer_customers`.`address_flag`, `customer_customers`.`created_by_id`, `customer_customers`.`created_at`, `customer_customers`.`updated_at` FROM `customer_customers` WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`customer_customers`.`created_at`, 'UTC', IST)) = 1
```

The manual query in mysql

```
select id,created_at from customer_customers;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | created_at                 |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2017-12-24 06:54:41.264756 |
|  2 | 2017-12-24 07:05:37.317395 |
|  3 | 2017-12-24 10:05:29.957158 |
|  4 | 2017-12-29 13:30:21.572926 |
|  5 | 2017-12-29 13:58:59.137774 |
|  6 | 2017-12-31 08:46:13.239080 |
|  7 | 2017-12-31 09:04:34.695830 |
|  8 | 2017-12-31 12:27:05.253016 |
|  9 | 2018-01-27 12:28:16.809840 |
| 10 | 2018-02-14 07:27:18.847884 |
| 11 | 2018-02-14 10:45:33.323448
```

Expected result should be 2

Comment: paste your `models.py ` here

Comment: @AstikAnand models.py added

Comment: Your query seems right.

Comment: @AstikAnand did you understood my problem

Comment: `Customers.objects.filter(created_at__month=1).count()` this is right. It should return 2. Try to filter using some other field.

Comment: i have tried other date time filed  seems no luk

Comment: Try to filter using some other field like `first_name` or so.

Comment: Other fields working perfectly only datetime field only issue

Answer (score 0):

> "When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current
>   time zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the
>   database."

Add this to your settings file.

USE_TZ = False